# Two Names in Field

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I am working with a scenario where I have 0 to 6 names in the field. For example, A2 has Bob Smith and Jone Random. Below is an example how they look in a check.

```
Effi Liu      
               <- (enter/gap)    
Kevin Xing
```

Basically, I want to generate a 1 column that counts how many people in A2. For example, two people and then create a function that will separate. Each of the names into different columns.

Comment: You can use a VBA user-defined function, starting with `Split(cellValueHere, vbLf)` and then loop over the resulting array (igoring empy values) to get a count.  Try that out then post back (with your code) if you run into problems.

Comment: @TimWilliams that will leave `vbCr` in the string. better split on `vbNewLine` (or `vbCrLf`).

Comment: @Mat'sMug -  I had `Alt+Enter` in mind (which I think is just vbLf) but you're correct it would be better to account for presence of vbCr also.

Comment: @TimWilliams you're right, it's Alt+Enter is just `vbLf` - TIL ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the names separated by the `Enter Key` in `Column A`, use the below formula in `Column B` and drag it to the right upto 6 or more cells and then drag down,

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,CHAR(10),"#"),"#",REPT(" ",999)),(COLUMN(A:A)-1)*999+1,999))
```

[image]

This formula splits your name strings with the `Enter Key` as the delimiter into multiple columns as you drag. You could then use `COUNTA` function to find the non-blank cells (number of names). I leave that part to you to google and find it. Hope this helped you.